# Is it possible to pass parameter as argument of a method like this in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass parameter to a method like this:

```
variable = my_method(:parameter)
```

No quotes, no nothing.Just -> :parameter .

Comment: Yes, assuming you want a literal `Symbol` object as the parameter. Could you give a little more context on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I downvoted because you can easily answer the question yourself.  Either just do a minimum of research or try it in irb: `def my_method(e); print "arg = #{e}, class = #{e.class}"; end`.  Then `my_method(:parameter) # => arg = parameter, class = Symbol`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can pass a symbol to a method.  Example:

```
puts('hello')
```

or

```
puts(:hello)
```